# Terminating Unused RF

Tags: rf

I am working on an RF design which includes multiple frequency synthesisers and sensitive receive stages. However I need to terminate an unused RF port on the synthesiser, what is the best way to do this?

I understand that you would normally use an RF 50 Ohm terminator, but there is no such connector as I am working at IC level, how do these terminators work?

Many thanks!

Comment: You'll need to provide more information than this, for instance what precisely does "working at IC level" mean? Do you understand why RF ports are terminated generally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will always have some way, appropriate to the level you are working on, to attach a 50ohm load to a port. If it's microstrip, then you'd use a 50 ohm resistor to ground, though two 100 ohm resistors in parallel often perform a little better, and will work for coplanar line as well.

However, if you have multiple synthesisers and sensitive receivers, crosstalk at RF is too easy to get and too hard to eliminate, that you probably don't want to be thinking about terminating an active output, but disabling it at the chip level.

It sounds like you're using a dual synthesiser chip and need only one output, but you don't say. Some designs of these will let you switch off the cahnnel or at least the output, for some the best you can do is turn the level right down. For others, programming the output frequency on that port to the minimum possible would make it easier to keep it in its cage.

Comment: Yes this is precisely what I am doing, apologies for my vague question as I needed a quick answer. 

I have seen in some designs that unused RF is connected to ground through a 50 Ohm resistor, but have then gone on to see revisions on these designs as this has caused significant problems. 

However in this case I have just verified that the other channel can indeed be disabled, preventing the RF from being radiated at all. 

I have included an MCX connector to one of the ends for probing, it might be useful in verifying that I am getting the correct LO frequency. 

Many thanks!!